# Should I open Source my iOS application?

Tags: open-source, licensing, ios

I developed an iOS application as a student and I am currently distributing it for free in the app store. I have received a few enquires about adding features to the app including one person who would like the app to be open source so they can add features themselves.

What concerns should I have if I open source my iOS application?

Which open source license should I use?

Comment: Any prohibition of Exclusive License (like GPL) in Apple's App Store?

Comment: Apple [doesn't allow GPL software](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/167797/could-apple-and-microsoft-allow-the-gplv3-on-their-locked-down-devices) in their App Store (as does Microsoft, by the way). Other Open Source licenses that don't require free redistribution (i.e. most others) don't seem to be a problem, 'though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **any open-source license you want, with the exception of the GPL**, which is incompatible with the Terms of Service of the Apple Store.

See the the regulations of the Apple Store [in the Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_App_Store#Regulations).

Comment: Presumably, it's not just the GPL that is disallowed, but any copyleft license which requires that source code be distributed along with object code. The GPL is far and away the most popular such license, but there are a few others.